# remove javascript from css3 animation

Tags: css

At the moment, I have a style like this:

```
.clip td{
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

I then add a css class and then use setTimeout to remove the class giving a simple fade animation.

Is it possible to achieve the same effect without javascript and have a complete css solution?

Comment: Different animation, but apart from that it seems to be the same question: [Simple CSS Animation Loop – Fading In & Out “Loading” Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985018/simple-css-animation-loop-fading-in-out-loading-text)

Comment: Can you make a working code sample that includes your JS? Does it get run on some event or click, or just as soon as the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS3 animation and use it's `delay` and timing functions. You probably still end up using JS to trigger the animation if it doesn't happens right after page load.

Chris has a nice article to help you understand and write CSS3 animations:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/