# Fadein/out texts with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to fadein and out texts with jQuery as bellow:

1. all texts are hidden by default
2. on pageload wait 1s,then fadein the first text (duration 500ms)
3. wait 500ms
4. fadeout the text (duration 500ms)
5. wait 1s
6. repeat
7. the fadein/out cycle must be an infinite loop
8. the number of text is dynamic (can be 2 or 39)

The HTML:

```
<div id="texts">
   <span>Text 1</span>
   <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can probably pull this off with css animation.  Go ahead, give it a whirl.  We'll wait right her if you need any help

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985018/simple-css-animation-loop-fading-in-out-loading-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of loops where you have to wait for a task to be done before doing the following animation is best achieved with a recursive function.

A named function expression is especially convenient here:

```js
$(function(){
  var texts = $('#texts span').hide(),
      i = 0;
  (function step(){
    i = (i+1)%texts.length;
    texts.eq(i).fadeIn(500, function(){
      texts.eq(i).fadeOut(500, step)
    });
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texts">
   <span>Text 1</span>
   <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an animation like:

```css
@keyframes flickerAnimation {
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
  0%   { opacity:1; }
  50%  { opacity:0; }
  100% { opacity:1; }
}
.animate-flicker {
   -webkit-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
   -moz-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
   -o-animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
    animation: flickerAnimation 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="animate-flicker">Loading...</div>
```